# How to make the script command append to a file?

Tags: command-line

The script command typecasts the terminal activity to a particular file. I understood that part, but is there a way it can be made to append to an existing file?

The end goal for me is to make the `script` append the data to an existing file with a timestamp that is achieved by the `date` command. And ultimately have a launcher that pre-executes this upon its launch and I have a logfile of every output on my terminal. I think I have the puzzle solved except for making the script command append.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the man pages says, the `-a` option is for append

```
script -a file
```

If file is missing, the default `typescript` filename is used.

Comment: dang! i forgot to go through the man pages yet again!!! Thanks a ton @enzotib ! Cheers!